# Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to verify integrity of data upload

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 SDK 1.9.8 jars to upload a file in the S3 bucket, but I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to verify integrity of data upload.  Client calculated content hash (contentMD5: CnXTOZv0aVBcfJK3iLvRCA== in base 64) didn't match hash (etag: 77252e2591a247069ada7642dae2ebd3 in hex) calculated by Amazon S3.  You may need to delete the data stored in Amazon S3. (metadata.contentMD5: CnXTOZv0aVBcfJK3iLvRCA==, md5DigestStream: null, bucketName: uai3037411-boomi-nonprd-integrations, key: INTERNAL/Stage/bzn)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1454)
    at s3.POC.main(POC.java:65)
```

below is the code I wrote for uploading:

```java
PutObjectResult result = s3Client.putObject("qa1-test-nonprd-integrations", "INTERNAL/Stage/bzn", new  File("D:\\Gegdc\\DS589668\\enovia\\Work\\phani.txt"));
```